# x86 Assembly - idiv to get decimal places

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-division

I'm limited to using the .386 with my current process. Using intel x86 how do I get the decimal places of a division? Basically I want it to output to the hundredth place like: 12.81

Here is my current code:

```
mov AX, Dividend
cwd
idiv Divisor

outputW AX ;Outputs Quotient (whole number)
outputW DX ;Outputs Remainder
```

I've tried multiplying AX by 100 first, but that still did not work for me. 
I'm also currently limited to making the variables `Dividend` and `Divisor` Word size. I tried replacing `cwd` with the `cwde` command, but that didn't work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Take the remainder multiply it by 100 and divide it by the original divisor. You will have to adjust it for rounding.

Comment: If you are in a 32-bit environment you can consider using 32-bit registers like _EAX_ instead of _AX_, and _EDX_ instead of _DX_.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks that helped. Now how would I go about moving the AX variable into the EAX, so that I could use the whole EAX? I was confused on how to go about doing that.

Comment: On a processor newer than the 286 you want to move a 16-bit value into a 32-bit register and zero extend it you could use `movzx` . Something like `movzx eax, word ptr [Dividend]` You can do sign extension with `movsx` . I may also have misunderstood what you were asking. I'm assuming MASM/TASM syntax since you mentioned the `.386` directive.

Comment: Yeah, I believe so. Everything is working much better so far though, I can finally see progress. After I'm done with the EAX register, how can I move the value back to an AX variable? I tried `movsx Quotient(Word Size), dword ptr [EAX]` that didn't seem to compile

Comment: `eax` is assembled from unnamed upper 16 bits, and lower 16 bits being `ax`, so you don't need to put value from `eax` into `ax`, it's already partly there (the lower 16bits of it). It's similar to how `ah`:`al` together form `ax`. But in the `ax = ah:al` case you can work with upper 8 bits directly trough `ah` alias. With `eax` you can't access upper 16b directly, only trough `eax` as whole. With 64b x86 machine the `rax` is again formed by `eax` supplying lower 32 bits of value, and unnamed upper 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply the dividend by 100 before performing the division, adjust for rounding, then divide by 100 again to get the two decimal places.  Since your initial code is 16-bit, here is a 16-bit solution first:

```
    ;; Perform the initial division (100 * Dividend / Divisor)
    MOV AX, Dividend    ; Load the Dividend into AX
    IMUL OneHundred     ; DX:AX = AX * 100
    IDIV Divisor        ; DX:AX / Divisor... AX=Quotient, DX=Remainder

    ;; Handle the remainder
    SHL DX, 1           ; DX now equals the remainder times two
    CMP DX, Divisor     ; Compare Remainder*2 to the Divisor
    JL l1               ; If Remainder*2 is <, we round down (nothing changes)
    INC AX              ; If Remainder*2 is >=, we round up (increment the quotient)
l1:

    ;; Divide by 100 again to get the final result
    CWD                 ; Sign-extend AX to DX:AX
    IDIV OneHundred     ; DX:AX / 100... AX=Quotient, DX=Remainder
    MOV IntegerPart, AX ; Now AX is the integer part
    MOV DecimalPart DX  ; And DX is the fractional part

OneHundred DW 100
```

Or, if a 32-bit solution is applicable, you can use 32-bit integers instead:

```
    ;; Perform the initial division (100 * Dividend / Divisor)
    MOVSX EAX, Dividend ; Sign-extend the Dividend into EAX
    IMUL OneHundred     ; EDX:EAX = EAX * 100
    MOVSX ECX, Divisor  ; Sign-extend the Divisor into ECX
    IDIV ECX            ; EDX:EAX / Divisor... EAX=Quotient, EDX=Remainder

    ;; Handle the remainder
    SHL EDX, 1          ; EDX now equals the remainder times two
    CMP EDX, ECX        ; Compare Remainder*2 to the Divisor
    JL l1               ; If Remainder*2 is <, we round down (nothing changes)
    INC EAX             ; If Remainder*2 is >=, we round up (increment the quotient)
l1:

    ;; Divide by 100 again to get the final result
    CDQ                 ; Sign-extend EAX to EDX:EAX
    IDIV OneHundred     ; EDX:EAX / 100... EAX=Quotient, EDX=Remainder
    MOV IntegerPart, EAX ; Now EAX is the integer part
    MOV DecimalPart EDX  ; And EDX is the fractional part

OneHundred DD 100
```

---

Note:  The 32-bit code is preferable since it does not produce [Divide Errors](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_137.html) from large quotients.  Consider `Dividend=32767` and `Divisor=1` in the 16-bit case:

- The first multiplication does: `DX:AX = 32767*100 = 3276700`
- The first division does:  `DX:AX / 1 = 3276700 / 1 = 3276700` (with a zero remainder), however `3276700` is too large to fit in `AX` (it is greater than `32767`) so a Divide Error is produced.

This does not happen on 32-bit because 3276700 can fit in `EAX`.  (Of course, dividing by zero would still produce an error in either case)

Another note: This code assumes the result of the initial division is positive

Comment: How would I go about outputting this to console with the decimal included? I keep getting a bunch of space due to the padded 0's. What does the `OneHundred DD 100` mean? Also, can you change this to be for signed numbers? I saw where you mentioned that the result of the initial division has to be positive.

Comment: In the 32-bit version, I might prefer `imul eax, eax, 100` / `cdq`, avoiding the need for OneHundred.  (That also lets you keep the sign-extended dividend around in a register other than eax if you want).  Of course, you need 100 as an operand for the second idiv, too.  `mov ecx, 100` / `idiv ecx` is more like what a compiler would emit (with `-Os`; otherwise it would replace division by a constant with a multiply by a modular inverse and some shifting.).